# What is the meaning of std::stack<int,std::vector<int>> s1;

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of `std::stack<int,std::vector<int>> s1;` in C++.
Can anyone clearly explain to me what is the meaning of the above statement...
Is it a stack of vectors?

Why are we adding a stack inside a vector?

It would be really helpful if anyone could answer at the earliest.

Comment: No one could explain it without context. Post the code snippet you see `std::stack<int,std::vector<int>> s1;` would help other to "guess" what writer wants.

Comment: The second template parameter is the underlying container to use. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: The definition of template for stack is ``std::stack<typename _Ty, typename _Container=deque<_Ty>>``

Comment: If you googled `std::stack`, you would find out at once that this is a stack on integer numbers implemented on top of a vector.

Comment: Please do not downvote this post bcz I am asking the definition, I am a beginner in C++ and new to StackOverflow, and when I searched online, everywhere I am just finding the definition. But I could not actually understand it, hence asked the question.

Comment: Closed for lacking details and clarity? I'm having a hard time figuring out how much clearer or detailed the question could get! Bods, if you *must* close, at least choose the right reason :-)

Comment: @srisubhashp _"everywhere I am just finding the definition. But I could not actually understand it, hence asked the question"_ If you already read the reference documentation, and just don't understand specific parts in it, ask about what you don't understand and make that clear in your question. But just asking fo an explanation unspecifically, isn't very useful. That's why we closed your question for _needs more details_. To ask about doubts or for clarification of the reference documentation is fine, you have to cite it though.

Comment: @paxdiablo ^That. "Can you explain _topic_" isn't a precise question. It should be obvious by your answer being overly broad and not detailed enough, as well as the subsequent comment Q&A: this is not well-scoped __at all__.

Comment: @PasserBy, the thing OP wanted explained wasn't a topic, it was a request to explain a *very* specific type definition. I can't see how my answer could be considered too broad since it explains exactly was was asked, I suspect we may just have to agree to disagree on this one. I do appreciate you explaining your position.

Comment: Just to clarify, I mean you start with the syntax, but goes on about how `std::stack` functions as a adaptor and the stack API. Yet, it isn't detailed enough that a user may learn how to use `std::stack` concretely, and why you'd want to specify `std::vector` in the first place. But yes, we will be disagreeing.

Comment: Thanks for all of your advice, from the next question, I will surely specify clearly. As now I understood the standard norms of StackOverflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type:

```
std::stack<int,std::vector<int>>
```

means that we wish to construct a stack of integers, with the container for the stack implemented as a vector of integers. More detail, in the unlikely event you need it, can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

In other words, create a vector of integers, then wrap the stack type around that.

A stack can be built from various underlying data structures, as long as they provide the facilities specified by a `SequenceContainer`, as well as `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()`. In the standard library, that means one of `vector`, `deque` (the default), or `list`.

---

Keep in mind that the underlying container in no way affects what you can do with the stack. You do not get direct access to that container.

So, for example, even though a vector allows random access, a stack built around a vector does not.

All you get is the standard stack methods: assignment, peeking at the top item, getting the size, checking if empty, pushing an item (in-place or move/copy), popping an item, and swapping the top two items.

Nowhere in that list can be seen affecting an element that's not one of the top two, something that would be relatively easy with a vector.

Comment: @peter So Does it mean that We are declaring a stack but can also adding the functionalities of a vector to it. Am I right...?

Comment: @srisubhashp: (1) Who is Peter? :-) (2) No, what you get is a stack, that's the interface you use. The container is not directly accessible to you, it's just what the stack will use for storing data. For example, while a vector would allow arbitrary random access, you cannot do that with a stack-using-vector - the only thing you can affect is the top entry (or top two, taking `swap` into account).

Comment: So now, we can use push_back function of vectors too for the stack...?

I am beginner in C++, but i am preparing in few days for a coding interview. Hence I am asking these doubts. When i try searching them on Google, I am just getting the same definition everywhere, so could not understand.Please do not mind.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I meant @paxdiablo.

Comment: @srisubhashp: no, you can't use `push_back`. The vector is what you tell the stack to use to weave its magic, you do *not* get access to that vector except through the stack API. I've updated the answer to (hopefully) make that clearer.

Comment: @srisubhashp stack acts like a power ranger suit. You may choose who (implementation) to wear the suit but you can't touch one's skin directly.